# WWW::Mechanize::Firefox and MozRepl

Tags: perl, ubuntu-12.04, www-mechanize-firefox

I wrote some code with help from examples but when I run it I'm getting error in Ubuntu Server 12.04.2 LTS:

```
Failed to connect to , problem connecting to "localhost", port 4242: Connection refused at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/MozRepl/Client.pm line 144
```

How can i fix this ?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;
use HTTP::Cookies;

my $username = "test";
my $password = "t3st";

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new();
$mech->get("http://test.com/login.php"); print "Logging, Please Wait.\n";
$mech->submit_form(
    form_number => 0,
    fields => {
        username => "$username",
        password => "$password",
    }
);
```

Comment: Have you tried `localhost 0 4242`?

Comment: this isn't a Perl question.  Your problem is either: 1., that no service (such as mozrepl) is listening on localhost port 4242, or 2., that your firewall is blocking or manipulating localhost traffic on port 4242 in such a way that connections to it immediately fail.

Answer (score 3):

- Install [MozRepl](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/mozrepl/) firefox add-on on your firefox
- Once installed, start the MozRepl in your firefox as below:

  Tools->MozRepl->Start
- Confirm that MozRepl is listening on port 4242 as below:

  ## netstat -anp | grep firefox

  tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4242          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1438/firefox

Good Luck !!

**Note**: I am not able to format this answer properly as SO formatting is not working as expected.

Comment: Under cygwin, the -p option for netstat expects a protocol specification, so -anp gives no output. You cannot grep firefox because netstat -an does not print the process name. So instead, use netstat -an | grep 4242

Comment: Better yet, telnet localhost 4242

Comment: @PhilGoetz, Never used Cygwin ever in my life. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to add to the answers above that since version 18, Firefox no longer displays the "Tools" menu unless you type the F10 key, or select "Options -> Menu bar".

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the mozrepl plugin installed and enabled and configured for port 4242?